# Railway ASP.NET app fails to build and I can't figure out why

Tags: c#, asp.net, railway.js

I'm trying to deploy a website using railyway, but every time I try doing so I end up getting an error:

> #13 2.186 /nix/store/zzpcf8ysd51a82rfhbs1wpygi1hqi6wp-dotnet-sdk-6.0.400/sdk/6.0.400/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(267,5): error NETSDK1064: Package MessagePackAnalyzer, version 2.4.35 was not found. It might have been deleted since NuGet restore. Otherwise, NuGet restore might have only partially completed, which might have been due to maximum path length restrictions. [/app/BugTrackerv2.csproj]

> #13 ERROR: executor failed running [/bin/bash -ol pipefail -c dotnet publish --no-restore -c Release -o out]: exit code: 1

> [9/9] RUN  dotnet publish --no-restore -c Release -o out:

> executor failed running [/bin/bash -ol pipefail -c dotnet publish --no-restore -c Release -o out]: exit code: 1

> Error: Docker build failed

I went into the package manager in visual studio to install MessagePackAnalyzer, but even after commiting the change it still  gives me the same error. The only reason I could think of why this is happening is because of NuGet restore, but it runs the --no-restore command. I haven't seen this error online when trying to look it up. Does anyone know anything about why this could be happening?

Here is the csproj file

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <UserSecretsId>aspnet-BugTrackerv2-046F28E1-A589-4F69-BE26-8712B9379A10</UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="MessagePackAnalyzer" Version="2.4.35">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.9" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.9" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI" Version="6.0.9" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="6.0.9" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="6.0.9" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="6.0.9" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem here. Just added a **.dockerignore** file with:

```
# directories
**/bin/
**/obj/
**/out/

# files
Dockerfile*
**/*.md
```

[print (file and content)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjRAl.png)